# Join a socket.IO room when an Express route is accessed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Having some trouble joining a socket.IO room when accessing a certain route in my Express app.

So I currently have the following set up:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var socketio = require('socket.io').listen(http);
var socketjs = require(libs + 'sockets/socket.js');

...

var server = http.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    debug('Taskful server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
    log.info('Taskful server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

global.socketIO = socketio;
socketjs.connect(server);
```

**sockets/socket.js**

```
var libs = process.cwd() + '/libs/';
var log = require(libs + 'log')(module);

module.exports.connect = function(server) {
    var io = global.socketIO;

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    //This comes through
        log.info('Connection to socket.io');
    });
}
```

**Route - projects.js**

```
var io = global.socketIO;

...

router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
    projectController.findByIdExtended(req, res, function(err, ret) {
        if (err) {
            res.redirect('/projects');
        }
        req.session.viewingProject = req.params.id;

        //I would like to be able to join the room here
        io.room = 'project_' + req.session.viewingProject;
        io.join(io.room);

        var db_project = ret[0];
        var db_tasks = ret[1];

        res.render('project', { user : req.user, project : db_project, tasks: db_tasks });
    });
});
```

As in the comments, I would like to join a socket IO room when the route is accessed.

I've tried `io.sockets.join` but they all come up as them not being functions. The global IO scope definitely comes through as I can see it the console log.

Is this easier to do so with EventEmitters and just receive the event to join a room in the **socket.js** file? If so, any ideas how to do so?

Much appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You call `socket.join()` on a specific socket.io socket.  You don't call `io.join()` or `io.sockets.join()`.  So, you need to get the specific `socket` object that you want to put in a room and then you call:

```
socket.join('project_' + req.session.viewingProject);
```

on it.

If you are trying to fetch the specific `socket` that is associated with the user that made the current route request, then you will have to set up an association between the socket and the route (usually using a known cookie identifier).  You can look up that cookie value from the route and then use that to find the right `socket` object for the current user.

It appears you are already using a session so there should already be a cookie identifier you could use to associate a route with a particular socket.io connection.  You may need to create a map object that associates these two in `io.on('connection')` and `socket.on('disconnect')` so you can then fetch the session ID and look up the right socket object in that map.

---

Note: Your use of:

```
var io = global.socketIO;
```

at the start of projects.js as a module variable is a bit of an anti-pattern.  This creates a module load timing dependency where the assignment to `global.socketIO` has to be done before the `projects.js` module loads or your code will not work.  Since module timing, particular with circular dependencies can be a complicated issue, this is not a desirable situation to create or have.

A slight change in your code to either not use globals at all (by explicitly passing the `socketIO` value to the projects.js constructor) or by just moving `var io = global.socketIO;` into each route that needs it as a local variable will completely remove this load timing dependency.